# For AAPL, How do You find how much volume typically trades on NASDAQ vs other exchanges?

Tags: nasdaq, nyse

Thank you for the knowledge shared on this site

wanted to ask this question below, in case someone kindly knows the answer

AAPL is listed on NASDAQ, but it is also traded on other exchanges like BATS.

How do you find around how much volume of AAPL typically trades on NASDAQ vs other exchanges?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can extract information/data like this from financial data vendors (Bloomberg, Reuters, etc.). I am going to explain how you can get volumes of a stock traded on different exchanges using Bloomberg:

- Type in the search box AAPL
- Hit
- Type in VWAP

[image]

Then you can play around with different parameters like `period`, `price`, `volume`, etc. Under the column `Breakdown` you have the names of the exchanges where the security is traded and respective volume under the column `Volume`.

You can also check the exchanges on [OpenFIGI](https://www.openfigi.com/search#!?pageSize=50&page=1&sort=EXCH_CODE&simpleSearchString=aapl&marketSector=Equity). Just refine the filter by selecting `Common Stock` in `Security Type`. Unfortunately, this page only gives the Exchange codes. Here is a [link](https://www.google.kz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjyvJKMzajVAhVDDJoKHQn_AhcQFgg2MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ultumus.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F01%2FBloomberg-Exchange-Code-to-MIC-Mapping.xlsx&usg=AFQjCNEG4qDqfUkUC0_iHTV_Mlv1SqJzvQ) to an excel file where you can find the full details of Exchanges by their code.

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

Most exchanges are disclosing security-wise traded volume on daily basis.

NASDAQ http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl/historical
NYSE https://www.nyse.com/quote/XNGS:AAPL

Also checkout https://www.bats.com/us/equities/market_statistics/execution_quality/symbol/?symbol=AAPL